# Android BackupManager not restoring after uninstall or other devices?

Tags: java, android, android-backup-service

I am using the `BackupManager` to backup `SharedPreferences` to the cloud. Now this works as expected when I use it on a single device and only perform a reinstall not a full uninstall. To do that I am clearing data which wipes prefs and than reinstalling the app from eclipse. If I first uninstall the app and after reinstall it the restore call reports no data to restore. The same happens when I install the app on another device.

From my understanding I would expect the data to be restored to any device regardless of the app being reinstalled or being a fresh install. Let me know if posting code will help but I figured that because it is working I might just have misunderstood what the service should be used for and how it works. I am trying to backup a users settings and possibly some information they enter into search fields. I would like this data to follow the user to a new device or if the user uninstalls the app and reinstalls at a later date. Please let me know if `BackupManager` is not the correct tool to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know from the words of Android Advocate:

> Generally it seems that `BackupManager` is only reliable for backing
>   up app data that will later be restored on the same device if the app
>   is re-installed from the Play Store.
>
> If you want to do backup syncing across multiple devices then you can try to use [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/), not `BackupManager`, and that there is very useful session from [Google I/O 2012 on the subject](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/705/).

Comment: I think your right, kind of a bummer because the BackupManager is fairly simple to implement. I am moving forward with a SyncAdapter interacting with Drive. Thanks for the input and the links.